# How to add/subtract two column values in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

How to add the code below more efficient ? Many thanks in advance.

```
  Total Operating Profit = 
    
    var _totOther =
    CALCULATE(
        [mymeasure] 
        ,dimAccount[FS Header Description] = "Total Other Operating(Inc)/Exp")
    
    var _direct =
    CALCULATE(
        [mymeasure] 
        ,dimAccount[FS Header Description] = "Direct Overhead without Allocations")
    
    var _Result = _totOther  +  _direct 
    
    RETURN _Result


# table view 
 FS Header Description                       mymeasure
    + Total Other Operating(Inc)/Exp           5
    + Direct Overhead without Allocations      10

# Expected Result 
  5 + 10
```

Comment: What is [Actuals - Currency]?

Comment: a measure to use in this calculation

Comment: We need more details on the measure and your data model. What is the performance issue?

Comment: please check out the question again

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Total Operating Profit = 


    [Actuals - Currency]( 
    dimAccount[FS Header Description] IN {"Total Other Operating(Inc)/Exp", "Direct Overhead without Allocations"})
```

Comment: awesome thanks a lot